# Navigation menu alignment with css

Tags: css, menu, navigation, alignment

I am trying to make a navigation menu based on the one found on the skype site but a more simple version.

So the menu consists of 3 items.

1. Logo
2. Navigation menu top row (2 items, language and special button)
3. Navigation menu bottom row ( 5 items)

Goal:
My final purpose is to get the two rows above each other to align to the right side (which I already managed)  and the logo to the left side. Further the logo has to be bottom aligned with the bottom row of the navigation menu.

See the picture:
http://i39.tinypic.com/2qa2zys.png

THE HTML CODE:

```
  <nav>
      <ul> 
      <li>
           <img src="images/lang.png" alt="Language" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" class="lang">NEDERLANDS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#" class="special">SPECIAL</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"/></a>
      <ul>

        <li>
           <a href="#" class="selected">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#" >HOE WERKT HET?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">HELP</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">PRIJZEN & AANMELDEN</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">INLOGGEN</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

THE CSS:

```
body { 
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Droid Sans ,Arial,'Liberation Sans',FreeSans,sans-serif;
    line-height: 14px;
    display:block; }


header nav li {
float:left;
margin-right:50px;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
}


header nav a {
font-weight: bold;
font-family: PT Sans;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
color: #333333;
text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}

header nav a:hover, a:active {
color: #0065f5;
}
header nav  .selected {
text-decoration:underline;
}

header nav ul {
float: right;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.special {
text-decoration:none;
color: white;
background: #0065f5;
padding:5px 15px;
text-shadow: #333333 1px 1px 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.special:hover {
 color: #fed000;
}

.logo {
float:left;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Don't style your LI, style your A tag. Don't float your UL. See: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could float left the logo and give a `margin-top` with the same amount of pixels as the language menu's height.
Or use `position: absolute`.

But what exactly did you **not** achive?
The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQTGu/) seems fine, but maybe the images (which are missing) are not positioned well.

Comment: Thanks Mikey. So what I basically did was get the logo image out of the list and put it between the two lists. And then float it to the left and give a margin-top of 30px, which aligns it as I wanted it to. It was that simple indeed, but some times if you sit on something for 5 hours, you lose oversight, especially when being a beginner like me.

Comment: Ok, no problem. If the layout messes up when your header contains more elements and you don't know how to fix this with floats, you could use `top: 30px` and `position: absolute` or `relative` to take some of your elements out of the regular flow.